# Is it possible to do custom text based syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I've been fiddling around to highlight specific piece of text in vs code (C-syntax in this case)
For example what I would like to do is display a certain piece of text (e.g. "PieceOfText") and colorize this.
What I tried was to add rules below to the user settings, but that didn't work out. The problem is that there isn't a specific scope, because I don't want to link it to a define, enum or any scope other than the text itself.

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "name": "PieceOfText",
        "scope": [
          "PieceOfText"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#FF0000",
          "fontStyle": "bold"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Use `https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight`

Comment: Thanks you, that helps! I'm now running in to a second issue, that I want to search on a specific string with only uppercase characters. for example I want to hilight "BLUE", but not "blue". is that possible?

Comment: change the setting `"highlight.regexFlags": "gi"` or `"regexFlags": "g"` property, if you don't add an `i` it is Case Sensitive

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm!